# IDirectSound8::CreateSoundBuffer returns DSERR_BUFFERLOST

Tags: windows, audio, directx, wav, directsound

What does IDirectSound8::CreateSoundBuffer returning DSERR_BUFFERLOST mean?

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee418039(v%3Dvs.85)) DSERR_BUFFERLOST isn't a valid return code from CreateSoundBuffer.

Two of our users have report errors where CreateSoundBuffer is returning DSERR_BUFFERLOST (out of hundreds).  We've shipped products with this code to thousands of users without any reported issues.  Both users report having latest sound drivers.  One reports having an Alienware 17 R4 laptop, the other an MSI laptop.

One user on Windows-10 reported that using Windows-8 compatibility mode fixed this issue.

Other internet references include this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/573678/error-creating-directsound-buffer-error-code-88780096).  One user tried restarting their Windows Audio service and it had no effect.  This [link](https://steamcommunity.com/app/525620/discussions/2/3377008022033351397/) seems to describe an identical issue in another game.

Here is the rest of the setup for that call:

```
WAVEFORMATEX w = {};
w.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
w.nSamplesPerSec = pSoundData->sampleRate;
w.wBitsPerSample = (WORD)pSoundData->bitsPerSample;
w.nChannels = (WORD)pSoundData->numChannels;

w.nBlockAlign = w.nChannels * w.wBitsPerSample / 8;
w.nAvgBytesPerSec = w.nSamplesPerSec * w.nBlockAlign;
w.cbSize = 0;

int bufferSize = pSoundData->decodedSize;


int bufferFlags = DSBCAPS_GETCURRENTPOSITION2 | DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME | DSBCAPS_CTRLFREQUENCY | DSBCAPS_CTRLPAN | DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS;

DSBUFFERDESC bufferDesc = { sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC), (DWORD)bufferFlags, (DWORD)bufferSize, 0, &w, DS3DALG_DEFAULT };


LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER pBuffer;
HRESULT hr = pSoundInterface->mDevice->CreateSoundBuffer(&bufferDesc, &pBuffer, NULL);
```

Comment: Is there a specific version of the OS involved in the repro? DirectSound has been legacy for many years so much of it is emulated by the modern versions of Windows so it's important to know what OS version.

Comment: The laptops are modern enough I'd be surprised if it's something other than Windows 10, but I've asked them to be sure.  Note this code runs successfully on other Windows 10 machines.

Answer (score 2):

The DirectSound docs haven't been edited in ages, but I can tell you that `DSERR_BUFFERLOST` is a valid error from a number of methods: `GetCurrentPosition`, `Play`, `Stop`, `Lock`, `Unlock`, and `Restore`.

DirectSound on all versions of Windows since Windows Vista isn't "direct" at all. It is using Windows Core Audio (WASAPI) to output. The primary reason you get a `DSERR_BUFFERLOST` is whenever you get a 'critical error' from WASAPI. Normally this only happens if you are losing the current playback device, but it's handled internally to switch devices so that really shouldn't be the case here.

If you are able to repro this issue, you could try enabling DirectSound ETW events to look for the error code happening here.

```
8a93b54b-c75a-49b5-a5be-9060715b1a33    Microsoft-Windows-DirectSound
ae4bd3be-f36f-45b6-8d21-bdd6fb832853    Microsoft-Windows-Audio
```

Otherwise, it could be a driver or hardware bug at play.